# Grabbing specific values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to programming and I'm tackling arrays. I thought I had multi-dimensional arrays figured out but I guess I don't. Here's the code I'm working on:

```
$loopcounter = 0;    
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
//...other stuff happens...
$allminmax[$loopcounter][] = array("$myrow[3]","$currentcoltype","$tempmin","$tempmax");
$loopcounter++;
```

}

This chunk of code is supposed to create an array of four values ($myrow[3], currentcoltype, tempmin, tempmax) and insert it into another array every time the loop goes through. When I do this:

```
echo implode($allminmax);
```

I get:

```
ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray
```

Do I need to implode each array before it goes into the master array? I really want to be able to do something like $allminmax[0][4] and get the $tempmax for the first row. When I try this now nothing happens. Thanks -- any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should either use `[$loopcounter]` or `[]`, but not both. You also should drop the quotes. They're unnecessary and in the case of `"$myrow[3]"` they interfere with the variable interpolation.

```
$allminmax[] = array($myrow[3], $currentcoltype, $tempmin, $tempmax);
```

By the way, arrays are zero-indexed, so to get `$tempmax` for the first row it'd be `$allminmax[0][3]` not `$allminmax[0][4]`.

Also, a better way to display the contents of your array is with `print_r` or `var_dump`. These will display arrays within arrays while a simple `echo` will not.

```
var_dump($allminmax);
```